# Why a block variable in scala function could not update after executed the inner block(s)?

Tags: playframework-2.0, postgresql-9.4, slick-3.0

I am new to scala. I have written a function named `calculateSubTotal` with a list of product id and quantities.

At first the function will pick up a product from the database for each of the product id, then calculate the `individual sub total` and sum up with `sub total`. I would like return the calculated sub total. Calculation is OK but unfortunately it returns the `initialized value` rather than the `calculated value`. Whats with my code. The code is as:-

```
def calculateSubTotal(productIds: Seq[Int], quantities: Seq[Int]) = {
  var subTotal = 0.0
  for (index <- 0 to productIds.length - 1) {
    val productId = productIds(index)
    val quantity  = quantities(index)
    val futureProduct = Products.read(productId)
    for {
      product <- futureProduct
    } yield {
      val listPrice = product.get.listPrice
      subTotal += listPrice * quantity
    }
  }
  subTotal
}
```

Look the above function always returns 0.0 as I have initialized. What will be the correct code?

Comment: What is the resulting type of `Products.read()` method? Is it `Future[Option[Product]]`?

Comment: Yes ... `Products.read()` returns `Future[Option[Product]]` @PawełJurczenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the resulting type of your `Products.read()` method is `Future[Option[Product]]`, which means that in your current code it's executed on a different thread. The main thread (the one executing `calculateSubTotal`) doesn't wait for a successful execution of `Products.read()` and it returns the result (`subTotal` in this case) right away. This will allow nondeterministic results: sometimes `subTotal` won't be modified at all, sometimes it'll be modified partially and sometimes you'll get a proper result. The simplest solution would be to synchronously wait for `Products.read()` result:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.Await

Await.result(Products.read(productId), Duration.Inf)
```

The asynchronous solution would require rewriting `calculateSubTotal` in a way, that returns `Future[Int]`.